# Getting the value from another column in the same row when leave a cell kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I want to edit a cell in kendo grid jQuery and when I leave the cell, I want the new value from the cell but also the value that the first column (portfolioCode) has in the same row. How is this implemented in kendo grid? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to post some of your code where you have tried this? That would help see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: Hello sbkrogers!Hopefully i find it after many hours researching. I wanted on the .change event of kendo grid the e.model.PortfolioCode which provided me the value of the portfolioCode from the same row of the cell i just clicked.